# 1 button Same Value 2 actions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have 2 forms that i need to merge, so that i only have a searchbox and one submit button. Maybe this is simple but i just don´t know how to do it.

The forms :

```
<form action="http://www.wixfilters.com/Lookup/Exactmatch.aspx?" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="PartNo" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Procurar" />
</form>

<form action="https://catalog.cumminsfiltration.com/catalog/CatalogSearch.do?&quot;" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input name="partNumber_PartDeatils" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Procurar" />
</form>
```

The value to search is the same, example search for 24073.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Clicking the submit button essentially works like clicking a link; how is the user supposed to visit two web pages at once? The first form leads to wixfilters.com, the second to catalog.cumminsfiltration.com, so which one is it going to be? You tagged this with `ajax`, do you want to grab the results using AJAX, then merge and display them? Even if that's possible, why not say so?

Comment: Hello I tagget this with ajax, because searching on google it seemed as the only solution for this case. The forms work on separe, as you can see they do da same thing in 2 diferent websites. The company has that 2 brands and wants to show 2 two options to the clients.

Comment: And yet you did nothing to attempt to use AJAX?

Comment: I dont even know what ajax is,I´m doing a website in webpress so my knowledge is not that good, but this would be great to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user doesn't need to go to the webpage you can use a cURL

for example make a form called submit.php in the same directory as your HTML file and change your form to this:

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="partNumber_PartDeatils" type="text" value="" />
<input name="PartNo" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Procurar" />
</form>
```

Then you submit.php file looks like this:

**submit.php**

```
<?php

$partNumber_PartDeatils = $_POST['partNumber_PartDeatils'];
$PartNo = $_POST['PartNo'];

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.wixfilters.com/Lookup/Exactmatch.aspx");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=$PartNo");

    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://catalog.cumminsfiltration.com/catalog/CatalogSearch.do?&quot");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var2=$partNumber_PartDeatils");

    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
```

If you need to handle the response data form two external URLs you are going to struggle and perhaps need to reconsider your site architecture.

Comment: Maybe this is possible but I need help.What if i make those forms hiden and then create a new one that populates those 2 and submits them.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to generate links to the same page that they then click.

For example:

**EDIT: I don't know the GET format for the destination URLs so you'll have to edit those bits to suit. As long as you keep the variables written as ' . $var1 . ' inside the echo query you should be fine**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Cummins Filters:</p><input name="partNumber_PartDeatils" type="text" value="" />
<p>Wix Filters:</p><input name="PartNo" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Procurar" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$var1 = $_POST['partNumber_PartDeatils'];
$var2 = $_POST['PartNo'];
if (!empty($var2)){
echo '<p><a href="http://www.wixfilters.com/Lookup/Exactmatch.aspx?PartNo=' . $var2 . '">Wix Filters</a></p>';
}
if (!empty($var1)){
echo '<p><a href="https://catalog.cumminsfiltration.com/catalog/CatalogSearch.do?&quot=' . $var1 . '">Cummins Filtration</a></p>';
}
}
?>
```

For example: http://main.xfiddle.com/code_57622035.php

Comment: If you're using wordpress this is the best method but you would need to have some knowledge about putting a PHP script on a Wordpress site. Is that something you're comfortable with?

Comment: I could use a plugin to help me with php script. But maybe this isn´t possible. What the forms do is  find the crossreference for that brand.